# Why Java is rounding my float calculation?

Tags: java, floating-point, int, double, println

I'm new to Java and I'm learning the first steps.

Doing my homework I have a problem printing a total with a floating point:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, Francesco");
        int myFirstNumber = (10 + 5) + (2 * 10);
        int mySecondNumber = 12;
        int myThirdNumber = myFirstNumber * 2;
        int myTotal = myFirstNumber + mySecondNumber + myThirdNumber;
        float  myLastOne = myTotal/10;
        System.out.println(myTotal);
        System.out.println(myLastOne);
    }
}
```

What Java prints is `11.0`:

```
Hello, Francesco
117
11.0
```

But instead it should print `11.7`:

```
Hello, Francesco
117
11.7
```

I know that the problem reside in line numbers 8 where I'm using `float`, I even tried using `double` but I have the same result

Comment: Dividing a value by an int returns an int. Rather use: float myLastOne = myTotal/10.0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of `int-division` as `10` is an `int`. You need to add the suffix **f** fo specify it's a float

```
float myLastOne = myTotal / 10f;
System.out.println(myLastOne); // 11.7
```

This would work also with `double`

```
double myLastOne = myTotal / 10.0;
System.out.println(myLastOne); // 11.7
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 
int / int makes int.
int * int makes int.
int + int makes int.
int - int makes int.

You must cast an int to float first.

```
float  myLastOne = (float)myTotal/10;
```

or

```
float  myLastOne = (float)myTotal/10.0;
```

Comment: float division int makes float.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is for the statement

```
float  myLastOne = myTotal/10;
```

if `myLastOne`, why is it not doing floating point division, but instead truncating the result of the division.

The reason is that although the variable `myLastOne` is a float, that line of code is first evaluating the expression `myTotal/10`.  Since `myTotal` and `10` are integers, it uses integer division.  This results in the integer result `11`, which it then stores in the `myLastOne` float variable, cast to `11.0`.

For Java to use float division, which is what you want, either `myTotal` or the number you are dividing by needs to be a float.

```
float  myLastOne = (float)myTotal/10;

int float = myFirstNumber + mySecondNumber + myThirdNumber;
float  myLastOne = myTotal/10;
```

Comment: the second example 'float  myLastOne = myTotal/10.0;'  is actually not working : "Error:(8, 34) java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float"

Comment: Edited.  It might be best to use `10f` or `10.0` as the divisor, but if the numerator is a float that will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Both `myTotal` and `10` is an integer, so Java thinks it should do integer division. Since the result is an integer, the `11.7` gets truncated into `11` (Which is `11.0` in float).

To make it output a float number (float division), define at least one of the operands as a float.

```
float myLastOne = (float)myTotal/10;
float myLastOne = myTotal/10f;
float myLastOne = (float)myTotal/10f; //All of these work
```